# When I uploading data, doubles fields Play framework

Tags: playframework, playframework-1.x

I don't know why, but when I am calling a `save` method, fields come to me like "Title, Title", "Body, body". Why it is happening?

Here is the method:

```
public static void save(News news, File img) {
        if (img != null) {
            try {
                FileUtils.deleteDirectory(new File(news.imagePath));
                String projectRoot = Play.configuration.getProperty("my.file.path");
                String fileName = String.format("%s.%s",RandomStringUtils.randomAlphanumeric(8), "jpg");
                FileUtils.moveFile(img, new File(projectRoot, fileName));
                news.imagePath = projectRoot + fileName;
            } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    news.createDate = new Date();
    System.out.println("save" + news.id + " " + news.title);
    news.save();

    news();
}
```

And in my HTML file I call my method with parameters `mews` and `img`:

```
#{extends 'main.html' /}
<meta charset="utf-8" />

<h1 class="page-header">Редактировать новость</h1>

<form action="@{NewsController.save(news, img)}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" value="${news.id}" name="news.id"> 
    <input type="hidden" value="${news.imagePath}" name="news.imagePath">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6">
                <label class="control-label">Заголовок</label> <input type="text"
                    class="form-control" value="${news.title}" name="news.title" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">Содержимое</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" name="news.body" rows="8">${news.body}</textarea>
    </div>

    <a href="#" id="pop"> 
    <img id="imageresource" src="http://androidnewspad.com/wp-content/themes/motion/images/genericlogo.png"">
        Click to Enlarge
    </a>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">Изображение</label>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6">
                <input id="file-0a" class="file" type="file" value="${img}" name="img"> <br>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Сохранить</button>

</form>
```

Comment: What's the meaning of the $ in `${news.id}`? I thought the magic character in Twirl, Play's templating language, is @.

Comment: $ used for define variable @ for call method